# How to filter stacked bar chart?

Tags: bar-chart, dc.js, crossfilter, stacked-chart

I found following example for a stacked bar chart with dc.js:
https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/stacked-bar.html

[image]
If I click on some (or several) legend item, I would like the chart to

- only show the corresponding items (e.g. red and blue) and
- adapt the total numbers to only consider the selected items

I already managed to add some click event to the legend entries:

```
chart.on('pretransition.hideshow', ()=> {
    chart.selectAll('.dc-legend-item')    
      .on('click', function (data, index, nodeList) {
        const stackName = data.name;
        if(data.hidden){
           chart.showStack(stackName);
        } else {
           chart.hideStack(stackName);
        }  
        dc.redrawAll();
      });
  });
```

This hides some stack but the sum is not shown as expected (multiplie, overlapping values are shown).

[image]

=>How can I filter the data correctly?

I also tried to use `chart.filter()` but that only seems to be able filter the x axis and not the stacks.

Currently, if I hover over a legend entry, the chart already adapts but does not show the wanted behavior.

Comment: Please try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39375071/676195

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Gordon I found following solution:

**Step 1:** Create an extra dimension for the stack property:

```
const stackDimension = crossFilter.dimension(d => d.stackProperty);
```

**Step 2:** Create an event handler and filter on that dimension:

```
  const selectedStackNames = [];

  const legendItemClickHandler = (data, index, nodeList) => {
   
    const stackName = data.name;       
    if(selectedStackNames.includes(stackName)){
       const index = selectedStackNames.indexOf(stackName);
       selectedStackNames.splice(index,1);          
    } else {
       selectedStackNames.push(stackName);          
    }

    if(selectedStackNames.length){
      stackDimension.filter((name)=>{
          return selectedStackNames.includes(name);
      });
    } else {
      stackDimension.filter(null);
    }  
    dc.redrawAll();
    
  };

  chart.on('pretransition.hideshow', ()=> {
    chart.selectAll('.dc-legend-item')
      .on('click', legendItemClickHandler);
  });
```

**Step 3:** Highlight selected legend items

```
 chart.on('pretransition.show', ()=> {
    chart.selectAll('.dc-legend-item')
      .on('click', legendItemClickHandler);

    const selectedStackNames = new Set(
      stackDimension.top(Infinity)
        .map(d=>d.stackProperty)
    );
    
    chart.selectAll('.dc-legend-item')
      .each((data, index, nodeList)=>{
        const node = nodeList[index];
        const colorRect = node.children[0];
        if(selectedStackNames.has(data.name)){
          colorRect.style.outline = "1px solid grey";
          colorRect.opacity="";
          data.hidden=false;
        } else {
          colorRect.style.outline = "";
          data.hidden=true;
          colorRect.opacity="0.3";
        }
      });
  });
```